# Ubuntu and MSSQL in Windows network

Tags: node.js, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, tedious

Ubuntu cannot connect to the MSSQL database that resides on the Windows network. When on the same PC only from Windows 10 the connection is successful.

I turned off the UFW firewall, installed smbclient, added these 2 lines to the smb config:

```
client min protocol = NT1
client max protocol = SMB3
```

I successfully connect to the machine on which MSSQL is installed (to the file system)

But from my code in node.js, the connection does not occur, at first I thought that the problem was in my code, but from DataGrip the situation is exactly the same

[image]

All credentials are entered correctly and all ports are open, the connection error says absolutely nothing, I'm at a dead end

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in SQL Server? The firewall being on on the ubuntu host won't change anything/much as it's an outgoing connection. Have you checked TCP/IP is configured on the instance?

Comment: Regarding TCP / IP: Exactly the same connection only from Windows is successful, and the rest of the developers from different projects are connected successfully via the same connection, I can’t see the TCP / IP setting specifically.

Where can I find out more about the database connection from Ubuntu? (by the way, I forgot to point out that I have Ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: Yes, but you said you're connecting from the local machine; you need TCP/IP for remote connections. You can find the TCP/IP configurations in the Configuration Manager.You didn't response about the logs either; what did you find?

Comment: Regarding the remote connection, the same project on Windows and special tools also on Windows to work with the database successfully connect and work with our database, also successfully connect, and there is no difference connected from the local network or via the Internet.

But when I try to make the same process from Ubuntu, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Regarding the logs, all I get in response from the database is this line, the project on node.js, the mssql library with version 4.3.2.

```[Database][2/25/2019 11:14:38 AM] Error while quering. Raw: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 192.168.2.3:1433 in 15000ms```

Comment: That doesn't look like a SQL Server log.

Comment: I probably did not understand correctly the question, tell me where can I find the server log?

Comment: Is SSMS, Management -> SQL Server Logs -> Current (most likely). Find the time you were trying to connect and what do you see?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs about my connection attempts ...

Comment: Then that means it's never getting to the SQL Server. Which could mean the connection string your entering is wrong; TCP/IP isn't enabled, there's a firewall on the host the instance is on, and is blocking the connection, or there's a firewall on your network, which is blocking connections between the 2 hosts.

Comment: Thank you. I will run all the tests from the same machine on Windows. At the end I will write.

Comment: OK, after several days of testing, it turned out that my code still connects, but through the tedious library in node.js, but I need to use the mssql library, I cannot understand why, for some reason, the DataGrip from Jetbrains does not connect, everything is fine with the server settings. .. In any case, thanks, I will open a new question regarding the mssql library :)